# connexion between Talend Open Studio and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, talend

when i want to make a connexion between Talend Open Studio and my data base i click on the button verify connexion , the porblem appears "you should to modify your data base"

Answer (score 0):

You have to workaround

**Setting up database connection between system.**

that is 
"https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforDataIntegrationUserGuide60EN/6.2.1+Setting+up+a+database+connection"

Please let me know if it is help you.

Comment: YOU CAN MAKE GREEN CHECKMARX  in that way you can accept this as answer